# Safari table cells border vertical-align

Tags: html, css, html-table, safari

Recently I have found a problem on Safari with table.
I have problem with red line (td bottom border or upper).
Here it is on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ryrmS/55.
And the full source:

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid red;">
            <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid blue; height: 156px;" rowspan="2">
            Content1<br/>
            Content2<br/>
            Content3<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-top: 2px solid green;">
            <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that the cells do not capture 50% of space in Safari but first takes 0 and third td takes all available height. It works in all browser except Safari.

Also I can't specify fixed height of div or td tag, because it it generated many times in my code and there are different heights and also many tables one inside another.

I can't figure out what the problem is with Safari and how to fix it. Does anyone have some hints?

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hm... Interesting. I suppose giving the two tds to the left a fixed height in pixels is out of the question? http://jsfiddle.net/ryrmS/57/

Comment: No i cant hardcode height as this construction is building trees in my application and dynamically add this blocks and height not always the same. Also if I. Use js to calculate and set height it takes 3 min (500 nodes) and that is not acceptable.

Comment: Found same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644171/how-to-set-50-height-for-table-cells-for-webkit-chrome-safari, and it seems that this was not working for webkit browsers, but for now it works in Chrome, but not in Safari so problem not resolved.http://jsfiddle.net/ryrmS/61/

Comment: As far as I know the specification's don't say how the browser must distribute the vertical space in the rows. Most implementations distribute it evenly (%) but safary just give the extra to the last one... (Take a look to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout ) You will have to go back to the js approach and find a better/faster algorithm. If you post a "big table" sample I'll be pleased to take a look. 500 rows doesn't seem so big to me to need 3 minutes, I guess it should be less than a second.

Comment: Thanks miguel-svq for explanation. Now it became more clear, but I want to find non-js solution. I don't give up. I try to rewrite it without table tags and now I have all fine in All browsers  except IE. http://jsfiddle.net/ryrmS/67/ and it looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/vC1ll.png. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are explicitly setting `height: 156px;` on the td that spans both rows, why not just set the other 2 tds to `height: 88px;`?

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74QdL/)***

## ***HTML***

---

```html
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid red; height: 88px;">
                <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid blue; height: 156px;" rowspan="2">
                Content1<br/>
                Content2<br/>
                Content3<br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: 2px solid green; height: 88px;">
                <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## ***CSS***

---

```css
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }
td { vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }
```

## ***RESULTS***

*(tested in FF, Chrome, Safari, and IE)*

---

[image]